# SQL - 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '' to data type int' behaving strange

Tags: sql

I am having problems with a query.

```
SELECT table_1.element_description, table_1.element_id, ISNULL(exercise_time_taken, '00:00:00') AS exercise_time_taken 
FROM (SELECT * FROM elements WHERE **`unit_id = 'ndb'`**) as table_1 
LEFT JOIN(SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(SS, SUM(DATEDIFF(ss, start_time, finish_time)),'20000101'), 108) AS exercise_time_taken, element_id 
FROM exercises 
WHERE exercises.user_id = 'my_email' **AND element_id <> ALL (SELECT unit_id FROM units)** 
GROUP BY element_id) as table_2 ON table_1.element_id = table_2.element_id
```

When i replace the highlighted line `AND element_id <> ALL (SELECT unit_id FROM units)`

WITH

```
element_id <> 'admin' AND element_id <> 'fc1' AND element_id <> 'ncc1' AND element_id <> 'ncc2' AND element_id <> 'nda' AND element_id <> 'ndb' AND element_id <> 'ngc1' AND element_id <> 'ngc1_demo' AND element_id <> 'ngc2' AND element_id <> 'ngc3'
```

Which is basically the long way of specifying which values not to select, the query runs fine a produced the desired output, if i dont do it this way then i get the 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ngc1' to data type int' error.

I would prefer not to manually code for each value as the list will grow over time and I will have to keep updating the query, which inevitably will be missed at some point causing more work than necessary.

Why does it do this? Even stanger depending on which unit i initially specify see sample line, it works for some and not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the data type of unit_id in the units table? If this is an int then that is why you are getting this error. It is trying to convert element_id to compare against your subquery values and the conversion fails.

Try using the following code and see if it works:

```
AND element_id <> ALL (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, unit_id) FROM units)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unit_id is allready an nvarchar. What I dont understand is when I replace the code with a check against each value seperately, as I have stated above it works.

Comment: I'm thinking the cause is the ALL keyword then, as that's the part of the expression you're doing away with. Are the datatypes for element_id & unit_id exactly the same? If not, it might be trying to convert them to some common denominator. I haven't worked with ALL very much, so am not quite sure of all the implications. Here's a link to MSDN detailing its use [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178543.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I dont think the ALL is the best way to check looking at the MSDN descriptions. I think I'll get a list of units and use a loop to create my query string. It means one more trip to the db but it's working doing it that way so I can make my peace with it. Cheers for the advice.